# How do I save/backup Halo (Combat Evolved) configuration and player saved checkpoints?

Tags: windows, halo-combat-evolved

So yes, if you read the title it **IS** Halo: Combat evolved, got it a few months ago.

It's time now to re-install and re-organize everything on my machine, so that would mean whacking everything very soon. I need to save my player checkpoints. I mean, I don't want to lose the checkpoints I've passed.

I have Win7 x64 and I see this path has something like *savedgames* :

```
C:\Users\<user>\Documents\My Games\Halo
```

Is this only it? Do I only need to copy this folder or are there others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the only folder you need to copy to back up your saved games (I've done this before).  Be sure to patch Halo after re-install *before* copying back the save data, as I believe the patch causes the game to overwrite that folder.

Comment: +1 thanks, can you elaborate on _patch_, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I believe the version of Halo on disk is v1.0 and it requires a v1.3 patch to play multiplayer.  I think the game will prompt you if it wants to be updated, so I would: 1) Install 2) Start it up 3) Patch if it wants to, start it up again 4) Exit 5) Copy over your saved files from backup.